# PFLoginViewController appearing

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm trying to setup the Parse PFLoginViewController to appear. Here's my class for one of my viewControllers.

```
import UIKit

import Parse
import ParseUI

class FirstViewController: PFLogInViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,  PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var textArray:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return self.textArray.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell


        cell.textLabel?.text = self.textArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

        return cell
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is, why is the PFLoginViewController appearing when I run the app? I'm not doing the setup code to make it appear, so I'm confused why it's appearing.

My guess is that somehow my viewController is being automatically replaced with the PFLogInViewController somehow because I included it in the top?

My project is a Swift app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FirstViewController` *is* `PFLogInViewController` (a subclass). If `FirstViewController` is the `rootViewController` of your app's window, or if it's the first/root view controller of a container view controller that is itself the window's `rootViewController`, then you will see the `PFLogInViewController` when you run your app.

When you define a class in Swift, the first type after the colon is superclass of that class (or, if the first type after the colon is a protocol, your class is a root class that does not inherit from a superclass).

Comment: My initial viewController is a Tab Bar controller. FirstViewController is the first tab.

Comment: And what is your tab bar controller's first view controller? `UITabBarController` is just a container controller that displays the content of view controllers in its `viewControllers` property.

Comment: It goes TabBar controller ->NavigationController->FirstViewController (which is a UITableView, although not as it seems it's become a PFLogInController), so I don't understand where my UITableView has gone? ideally the PFLoginViewController would be something which appears optionally, if needed.

Comment: So `FirstViewController` is the first content view controller seen by your app on launch (`UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` are both container view controllers - they don't display content of their own, just the content of their children). `FirstViewController` is not a `UITableView` - a table view is a view, not a view controller. `FirstViewController` is a subclass of `PFLogInViewController`, which is why you are seeing it when you run your app. Without wanting to sound harsh, I think there are some basics you need to revisit before proceeding.

Comment: Sorry, I think you meant to imply that `FirstViewController` is a `UITableViewController`. This still isn't quite true, although you have made it behave like one by giving it a `tableView`, and by making it the table's delegate & data source. Regardless, your view controller will still inherit all the behaviour of `PFLogInViewController` because it is a subclass of that class. What navigation flow are you trying to achieve in your app (when/where _should_ your log in view controller be showing)?

Comment: Ha, doesn't sound harsh at all, you're right it would help if I had a more base understanding of all of this, right now I'm trying to learn by just doing, the navigationController contains a TableView, which is inside a viewController, the flow I want, is just the PFLogInController comes up if the user is not signed in, or if the user taps on a "LogIn" button at some point, ok so basically I need to create a whole new viewController for the PFLogInViewController? although in the examples that controller appears via code, not the storyboard

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question, but yes, your `PFLogInController` should be a separate VC that you "present" (modally, most likely). Each VC manages a 'unit' of content (a unit is often - but not always - a 'screenful' of content), and VCs can "present" other VCs. you need to perform some check when your app starts to determine whether or not the user is logged in, and if they're not, instantiate your log in VC and present it. This can be done either programmatically or using segues in your storyboard, whichever is most appropriate. Similar process for the "Login" button.